# how can i put this program in recursive (python)?

Tags: python, recursion

How can I put this in recursive? This is an assignment to calculate the factorial of a number and tell if a number is prime or not only using addition and subtraction, but it needs to be in recursive form but I can not figure out how to do it.

```
def Prod(x,r):
    z=0
    while x>0:
        z=z+r
        x=x-1
    return z
def Fat(x):
    r=1
    while x>1:
        r=Prod(x,r)
        x=x-1 
    return r
```

AND

```
def Divi(x,d):
    c=0
    while x>=d:
        x=x-d
        c=c+1
    return x
def Pri(x):
    r='N'
    d=2
    while d<x and r=='N':
        if(Divi(x,d)==0):
            r='S'
        d=d+1
    if r=='N':
        t='its prime'
    else:
        t='not prime'
    return t
```

Forgot to mention that also I can only use `if ... elif ... else` nothing but that

Comment: Your question is off topic on SO. Start by learning how recursion works, looking at examples of recursion, wriring simple recursive programs in Python. Recursion is hard. It takes time to learn how to think recursively.

Comment: To learn how to understand recursion, you must first learn recursion.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function is just a function that calls itself.

```
def me():
    me()
```

except, the most trivial recursive function, given above, recurses forever, just like an infinite loop loops forever:

```
while True:
    dab()
```

So what do you do to prevent the infinite loop? You have a loop condition:

```
x = 3
while x > 0:
    dab()
    x -= 1
```

Now your loop will exit. So how do we prevent a recursive function from looping infinitely? We provide a *base case* where the recursive function does *not* call itself:

```
def dabr(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return
    dabr(x - 1)
```

In your code above, you exit the loop when `x>1` is no longer true. That's your base case. So write that as an `if` statement, such that the function *recurs* on itself only when `x>1`. Here's a hint:

```
def Fat(x):
    if x <= 1:
        return ???
    return ???
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are programming recursively, you are calling a function into itself.

```
def Prod(a, b):
    ...

def Fat(r=1):

    if r <= 1:
        return 1

    else:
        return Prod(r, Fat(r - 1))
```

In this case, you are calling the function `Fat` inside itself.